# How if I don't want the note of a particular chord to be played, and how should I write the notation for it?

Tags: chords

For instance, the chord Cmaj9, I do not want the **E** note to be played in this chord, then how should I write the notation to indicate this so that the player knows it?  And for "rootless voicing", it is acceptable to use the notation "Cmaj9", even though I don't want the note, **C** to be played, right??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of thing is difficult to notate with a chord symbol. You could try `Cmaj7sus2`, or `Cmaj9(no3)`. Both are clumsy.

Generically, the best way to specify a voicing is to use actual notation. Chord symbols can carry some voicing information (c.f. `C` with `C/E`), but they are usually quite vague. For example, you can't really specify a rootless voicing with a chord symbol. If they are idiomatic to the genre, a player may automatically use one. But it's not explicit in the chord symbol.

In short, if you require a specific voicing, chord symbols are the wrong tool for the job. You'll need to use something more specific, and standard notation is almost always the best option.

Comment: For the **CMaj9** without the E, why not use **G/C**?

Comment: Like a second inversion of it? The G being the "root" / bottom note, right? The player could have played the E though, with G/C add 9

Comment: @YauQiHerng -- not a second inversion, a slash chord. **G/C** would be a G major triad with a C in the bass, i.e. C - G - B - D, which are the notes of a **CMaj9**, without the E.

Comment: This's a real good alternative!